# Visual studio merge problems with new line

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2017

I'm having trouble with automerge i Visual Studio 2017.
When i try to add or remove a line break in my code, git sometimes refuses to automerge the file and I have to accept every single added or removed line break.

Old code:

```
        if (someThing != null)
        {

            if (presentation)
            {
```

New code:

```
        if (someThing != null)
        {
            if (presentation)
            {
```

Comment: I think it's <CR/LF> problems. Check encoding in you viusal studio.

Comment: How do you have your line endings configured?  Do you have a `.gitattributes` file set up?